# Can't find libusb-1.0-0-dev package

Tags: 14.04, apt, hp

I am running hplip and it tells me I need to install several packages.

It tries to install these packages and fails. One of the packages is libusb-1.0-0-dev.

I tried running `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev` and I get the error

```
Couldn't find any package by regex 'libusb-1.0-0-dev'
```

I know the package exists because it has it [own page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libusb-1.0-0-dev) on packages.ubuntu.com. What is the reason I can't get this package? I assume I'll be able to fix the rest too, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, but you can also download libusb-1.0-0-dev for Ubuntu 14.04 manually from its [official Ubuntu download webpage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libusb-1.0-0-dev). At this webpage there is a table from which you can select your OS's *Architecture*, either [amd64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libusb-1.0-0-dev/download) or [i386](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libusb-1.0-0-dev/download), and then click one of them to take you to the download page for the libusb-1.0-0-dev .deb file. After downloading the .deb file, double-click it to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.

The reason why you can't get this package may be related to the reason why a package has also been reported as missing from the default GNOME Software application in Ubuntu 16.04. When I researched this missing package, I found out that it could still be downloaded manually from some servers, but it could not be downloaded manually from all of the available servers. Instead of downloading the .deb file, clicking on the download link opened a webpage full of garbled, meaningless text.

Comment: This is working. It was simple for libusb-1.0-0-dev, however the other packages have lots of dependencies and I have to get each one.

Comment: That's no good. You could try changing the server that you are downloading software from. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and select *Edit* -> *Software Sources* -> change the server to the right of *Download from*.

Comment: I hit a dead end with libcups2-dev. Down down down in its dependencies  it required a version of libcomerr2 that I can't get. I am stumped for now. I'm upgrading to 16.04 (which I was having other problems with, hence the delay) to see if that helps.